# How to find Reliability of a rectangular distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that the failing of a device is equally probable within an interval [a,b] such that the fault density is:

*f(x)* = `{1/b-a if a<= t <= b`

```
       0  otherwise}
```

Can somebody help me out in finding the Reliability function *R(t)* for that device.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think "fault density" is a standard term, though that might depends on the field. Do you mean hazard function?

Comment: @Gina: I have seen failure pdf. I think the hazard function is something like $-{R'(t) \over R(t)}$. But its been a long while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform the computation using:
$R(t) = p \{\omega |  T(\omega) > t \} = \int_t^\infty f(x) dx$.

It may help to draw $f$ and think about what $R(t)$ means in terms of the graph of $f$.

It should be clear that no devices fail for $t<a$, and that all devices fail for $t>b$. This tells you what $R(t)$ is for these ranges.

Remember that $f$ is a pdf.

Consider three cases:

(1) $t<a$:

> We have $R(t) = \int_t^\infty f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x) dx = 1$.

(2) $t \in [a,b]$:

> $R(t) = \int_t^b f(x) dx = {b -t \over b-a}$.

(3) $t >b$:

> $R(t) = \int_t^\infty f(x) dx = 0$.

Comment: for case 1. it gives _a/b-a_ and for case 2. it gives _1_ and for case 3. it gives _b/b-a_ . are these correct ? I am still confuse, how should I conclude the result ? Can you please elaborate a little more ? Thanks !!

Comment: First think about the problem. If the device never fails for $t<a$ what will be $R(t)$ for $t<a$? Remember that $R(t)$ is the probability that it will last longer (strictly) than $t$.

Comment: Second do the computation. For $t<a$ we have $R(t) = \int_t^\infty f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x) dx = 1$.

Comment: The same sort of reasoning applies to $t > b$.

Comment: (Also, the curve must be continuous. So that would exclude your answers for Cases 1,2.)

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks a lot.. You just saved my day :)

Comment: Delighted to be able to help.